# With regard to distributive law of inner product in vector algebra

Tags: vectors, vector-fields

Consider the equality

\begin{align*}
&\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}+c=0 \\
\implies &\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}+\frac{\vec{a}}{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}}c)=0.
\end{align*}

If the above equation is valid for any $\vec{a} $, can we say the following equation is valid?

\begin{align*}
&\vec{b}+\frac{\vec{a}}{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}}c=0\\
\implies & \vec{b}=-\frac{c}{|\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}|}\vec{a}
\end{align*}

I feel something (in particular, with regard to sign) is wrong.

Can the above process be justified?
If not, let me know the reason.

Comment: This seems to be a question for Mathematics SE.

Comment: It's not valid for $\vec{a}=\vec{0}$ because $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}=0$.

Comment: @TheAverageHijano Thanks. Right! If $\vec{a}$ is not  zero vector, is it valid?

Comment: It doesn't matter if $\vec{a} = \vec{0}$ if it's true for every vector $\vec{a}$. The fact that it in particular holds for $\vec{a} = \vec{0}$ is of no consequence. At least if we begin at the second equality.

Comment: @InertialObserver, I didn't say that it holds for $\vec{a}=\vec{0}$, I said that it **does not** hold for that case.

Comment: Yea you’re right. The condition has to be that it’s not zero. I’ll edit my answer

Comment: Could you please write a topic line that's more descriptive?

Comment: @pipe Okay. I will do that soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is clearly wrong, because it says that $\vec b$ is proportional to $\vec a$, i.e. they must point in the same direction. But if you add to any such $\vec b_0$ a vector $\vec{b'}$ which is **perpendicular** to $\vec a$, then the product $\vec a . (\vec b_0+\vec{b'})$ is the same so your first equation still holds for any $\vec b=\vec b_0+\vec b'$.  This equation tells you the component of $\vec b$ along $\vec a$, but the component of $\vec b$ perpendicular to $\vec a$ is completely arbitrary.

The error comes in the step (which you rightly have a question mark against) that your second equation is true for all $\vec a$, so the bracket must be zero.  This works for 
$a f(b,a)=0\  \forall\  a \implies f(b,a)=0$ but not for  $\vec a.\vec f=0 \ \forall \ \vec a \implies \vec f=0$. You cannot create 3 equations from 1 equation.

The glitch in @InertialObserver's proof is that their $\vec b$ is a different $\vec b$ for  $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: Yea, now that I think about it.. you’re right.. that’s what I get for answering  questions at 2 am

Comment: Unfortunately my answer has been accepted so I can’t delete it to defer to this answer

Comment: It's a very subtle point. Easy to go adrift. Specially at 2am.

Comment: @RogerJBarlow Thank you for your answer. I want to write the equation in a form of $\vec{b}= something $. I'd appreciate it if you could tell me what to do.

Comment: Something like $\vec b = -{c \vec a \over |a^2|} + \vec d \times \vec a$, where $\vec d$ is any arbitrary vector. The scalar triple product formula ensures $\vec a .(\vec d \times \vec a)=0$

Comment: @RogerJBarlow Now, I remember I learned something similar in the vector analysis part of the electromagnetism textbook a long time ago. Thank you very much.